# Should I help this young Magpie?

Tags: ornithology

I found this young Eurasian Magpie in my garden:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

He is just standing there, not doing anything. I believe he fell from a tree and can't fly yet and is just waiting for the feeding from his parents until he can fly, but I wonder if that’s true and if I should do anything to help.

There’s another young one on a branch of a nearby tree, also:

[image: 3]

Comment: Call the RSPCA or whatever animal rescue service there is in your area. Posting it on SE doesn't help the critter in any way I'm afraid.

Comment: @AliceD my question was precisely if there is something I should do, or if this just normal in the bird's growing process

Comment: And my answer is precisely call the RSPCA or whatever animal rescue service there is in your area. Posting it on SE doesn't help the critter in any way I'm afraid.

Comment: @AliceD actually it _does_ help the critter. The OP didn't know what to do, and didn't want to interfere without knowing if he/she should, so came here to ask someone who knows better, which in my opinion was a good thing to do. And you, presumably someone who knows better, said call RSPCA, which is useful information the OP received he/she didn't have before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's best to leave the bird alone. The parents are likely still in the area and tending to the young, including feeding and chasing away would-be predators. You're better off staying away so as to not intimidate or upset the parents. If you have outdoor pets, relocate them indoors or to an enclosed area for a few days.

Failing this, the advice given in comments to call your local animal rescue is best.

Comment: I actually saw a pair of adult magpies chasing off a hawk in the sky later, so maybe those are the parents. Thank you for the answer

Comment: check the guides "what do I do if I find a young bird on the ground"... if there are no cats it should be ok.